# Error al levantar servidor en Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, servidor

Necesito ayuda con este error, soy nuevo en esto y no se porque me sale esto

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/admin1/Aplicacion/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con `gem install bundler`?

Comment: Y luego un `bundle install`

Comment: Lo intente pero siempre al iniciar el comando de levantar el servidor me sale que las gemas estan perdidas o algo y me pide que ejecute bundle install y siempre asi

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna otra versión de ruby instalada?, ¿qué resultado obtienes si ejecutas el comando `echo $GEM_PATH`?